# How to use Curl to Post to Miscrosoft Teams channnel

Tags: php, curl, post, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a simple message to a team channel, and here's what I have tried:

```
$link = 'My-Link-Goes-Here';
$curl = curl_init($link);

$postfields = array(
    'text' => 'HELLO',
);
$postfields = json_encode($postfields);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($curl);
```

what did i've done wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer to myself, if it can help anyone :

```
function Webhook($Name){
    $url = 'My Url Goes Here';

    $ch = curl_init();

    $jsonData = array(
        'text' => 'Hello '.$Name.' !!'
    );
    $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData, true);


    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: Hello @moonshine, i have try your script, but i get as result => bool(false)
Do you have an idea why? Can't figure out, please help! greetings

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer, but i have clearly not idea, could you share me the code you made on a pastebin, i'll try to help you